# Where does visual composer store links?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, visual-composer

I am trying to target all links with no www. in the database.

https://launchhousing.org.au

and replace with

https://www.launchhousing.org.au

I have used the 'search and replace' plugin which has apparently changed all of the links but somehow Visual Composer seems to still have links without the www. I am using the VC 'Icon Box' and added in the URL field: http://launchhousing.org.au/category/policy-agenda/

Answer (score 12):

Visual Composer store links in urlencode format as:  
 `link=\"url:http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Findex.php%2Fmembership-account%2Fmembership-levels%2F|||\"`

That's why you can't find.

You need make sql dump of your database and make replacing:  
**http%3A%2F%2Foldsite.com%2F** → **http%3A%2F%2Fnewsite.com%2F**
  
I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: To complete this answer, This site [encode-decode](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) Encodes urls, then with a simple Database Search and Replace plugin like [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) you can change any links.

Answer (score 0):

You mean links that are in the page/post content? These will be in the `post_content` of the `wp_posts` table, along with the rest of the content. All the VC elements you put into a page/post are just shortcodes.

Though I also have found that plugins, such as `WP DB Migrate` seem to miss VC stuff in the post_content column.

I always have to manually do an SQL query. You can do this in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'launchhousing.org.au', 'www.launchhousing.org.au')
```

And remember to change `'wp_posts'` if your prefix is different.